# User specific temporary storage in PHP

Tags: php, storage, temporary

I there any way I can store some simple, user specific data without having to store it permanently? I am trying to use ajax to load up some ads, and then have the PHP file choose the ad based on the ads that have already been displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: Thanks! What a simple answer! *I can't accept it for a coupla mins*